# Magento - Display cart shipping cost in 'Cart View'

Tags: php, magento, mage

I've setup a german magento store and I'm struggling with displaying the total shipping cost.

This problem is really bugging me. I try to display the total shipping cost in the magento 'cart view' (Just one tiny step before the checkout).

I've setup table-based shipping and it's working fine in the checkout process at least...
I tried googling before asking this question but none of the answers helped me at all because most of them are over 3 years old.

---

*My question in short:*

Is it possible to get the shipping cost (based on the current items in cart) via **PHP**?
Is there a specific block or helper I can call to get the shipping cost?

I wan't to get the shipping cost at **grandtotals.php** in `%my-theme%/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.php`

I've tried the following solutions:

```
 <?php $k =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
  echo $k['shipping']->getData('value'); ?>
```

or:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

and several other solutions. Maybe these don't work for magento 1.8?

Could you guys give me a clue or possibly a *super short* tutorial how to set up these **Magento Event Observer**?